# Android buttons, all equal height to fill to bottom of the screen, all resolutions

Tags: android, xml, button, textview, android-relativelayout

Is there a way of making Android buttons in xml all equal height to reach the bottom of screen with all resolutions of screens. So no matter what screen resolutions the phone is the app will make the buttons fill to bottom of screen.

This is what I have so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#DEC779" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/playiconw"
    android:text="Back"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/playiconw"
    android:text="Go"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/playiconw"
    android:text="Left"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/playiconw"
    android:text="Right"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/playiconw"
    android:text="Up"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="DOWN"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your buttons in a LinearLayout and make `layout_height="match_parent"` to all of them and add `layout_weight="1"` to all of them. That should work as the weight can be used as some kind of percentage/relative value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#DEC779" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="DOWN"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:gravity="center"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_above="@id/textView2">
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/playiconw"
    android:text="Back"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/playiconw"
    android:text="Go"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/playiconw"
    android:text="Left"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/playiconw"
    android:text="Right"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/playiconw"
    android:text="Up"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Layout_weight does not work with relative layout but thanks for help :D

Comment: Thats why I said that you should put the buttons in a LinearLayout. it is the only way to make sure that your both textviews at top/bottom will be there.

Comment: Updated my answer to show the (untested) layout code. Might be that you need to set the orientation of the LinearLayout by hand...

Comment: Thanks so much! just the first and last button goes over text any help?

Comment: Don't really want to change to LinearLayout as I want text to be centered :/

Answer (score 0):

yes using the relativelayout make the buttons attach to the bottom of the relativelayout.

make the height a fix height.
and align to parent bottom

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

so each button is:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/playiconw"
    android:text="Back"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"/>
```

Comment: This just make 1 of the buttons really big and fill up whole page :/

Comment: apply the same thing to all buttons, then select where to align the top of the button..also since you are laying it bellow the textView I suggest you remove my height suggestion..see my edit.

Comment: Still does the same, Thanks for help though!